# Can I set up IIS 8 to reverse proxy some POSTs to an external server?

Tags: reverse-proxy, iis-8, arr

I've pointed www.myoldsite.com to a new IP address, and that IP address hosts www.mynewsite.com on IIS8.  I'm trying to reverse proxy some POSTs back to www.myoldsite.com via ARR but I'm not able to get it to match the Request URI pattern.

I have ARR enabled on www.mynewsite.com, and the "Proxy Type" is set to "Use URL Rewrite to inspect incoming requests".  The Reverse Proxy is "www.myoldsite.com".  Then I have URL Rewrite rule which matches a regular expression "(.*)" and has a condition which should match a REQUEST_URI with the pattern "MyOldForm.aspx".  The action is set to redirect to www.myoldsite.com/{R:0}.

However, when I post to the url http://www.mynewsite.com/MyOldForm.aspx, I get a 404 error, meaning the pattern isn't getting matched.

I also tried setting the external site as a "server farm", and also setting up a rewrite rule in the site itself, but the rule isn't getting invoked in either of these cases.  Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: This should be possible. As you said the pattern/conditions aren't being met in the rewrite rule, test those further.

Comment: Thanks---I was able to get the pattern matching but then I got stuck with a 502 error.  Error logging didn't log anything useful.  After wasting an entire day on ARR I gave up and switched to Helicon APE, and got it working in five minutes with a two-liner.   Looks to me like Helicon is more powerful at managing IIS rewriting and proxies than IIS itself is.